# darkflow error when detecting on raspberry pi zero: undefined symbol: _ZN6google8protobuf8internal26fixed_address_empty_stringE

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, darkflow

currently I'm trying to run darkflow on RPi zero with it's camera installed.

detection using darkflow is a little bit slow but working quite well on pi 3.
(took several hour to compile opencv3 though)
So I thought it's similar on pi zero, but it wasn't.

I managed to install opencv 3.3.1 (took a day to build) and tensorflow ( using
tensorflow-1.4.0-cp35-none-any.whl  renamed from tensorflow-1.4.0-cp34-none-any.whl ), and they are working fine (sort of... tensorflow shows some warning due to python version incompatibility - but it's working anyway according to Pete Warden's blog: https://petewarden.com/2017/08/20/cross-compiling-tensorflow-for-the-raspberry-pi )

built darkflow with

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

without any problem. ( it's actually python3, for I'm on venv with python3 )

But when I try to check if detection works with following commands:

```
./flow --imgdir=sample_img --model cfg/tiny-yolo-voc.cfg --load bin/tiny-yolo-voc.weights --gpu 0
```

it gives error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./flow", line 4, in <module>
    from darkflow.cli import cliHandler
  File "/home/pi/tensor/darkflow/darkflow/cli.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .net.build import TFNet
  File "/home/pi/tensor/darkflow/darkflow/net/build.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .ops import op_create, identity
  File "/home/pi/tensor/darkflow/darkflow/net/ops/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .simple import *
  File "/home/pi/tensor/darkflow/darkflow/net/ops/simple.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow.contrib.slim as slim
  File "/home/pi/tensor/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/__init__.py", line 82, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.eager.python import tfe as eager
  File "/home/pi/tensor/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/tfe.py", line 76, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.eager.python.datasets import Iterator
  File "/home/pi/tensor/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/datasets.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.data.python.ops import prefetching_ops
  File "/home/pi/tensor/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/data/python/ops/prefetching_ops.py", line 25, in <module>
    resource_loader.get_path_to_datafile("../../_prefetching_ops.so"))
  File "/home/pi/tensor/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/util/loader.py", line 55, in load_op_library
    ret = load_library.load_op_library(path)
  File "/home/pi/tensor/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/load_library.py", line 56, in load_op_library
    lib_handle = py_tf.TF_LoadLibrary(library_filename, status)
  File "/home/pi/tensor/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 473, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /home/pi/tensor/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/data/python/ops/../../_prefetching_ops.so: undefined symbol: _ZN6google8protobuf8internal26fixed_address_empty_stringE
```

I have no idea what's wrong and how to resolve this. Could you help?

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue. After wasting 4 days I decided to try out older builds because maybe they would work. I found a build that didn't have this error. It is for python 2.7 though so I had to change some of my code. http://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-pi/78/artifact/output-artifacts/tensorflow-1.3.0-cp27-none-any.whl